# calculate a simple expression in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, stack

how I can evaluate that infix expression in java : ((1)*2/4+2-1).
I knew that I can use 2 stacks : 1
1st for characters(*+-/).
2nd for integers.

then check for priorities of the characters and calculate simultaneously!?

So is there a more perfect way for calculating like that expression?! ..

Thanks,

Comment: Does this help? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression

Comment: Post your code and we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing a calculator?
Look at [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for this algorithm (that might help you). You can also use third-party library for this or dynamic language (Javascript Engine/Groovy/BeanShell/Google: java calculator library/etc.)